# Javascript retain event data when using replace with

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Im trying to keep the event data when replacing a div with replaceWith(). When I try it it cannot find the event. Currently I'm using postmessage to call the message event lister to replace a dive with a script inside the element (for when the message event is not being called)

```
// Create IE + others compatible event handler
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
// Listen to message from child window

eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    console.log('origin: ', e.origin);

    // Check if origin is proper
    if( e.origin != 'http://domain.com' || e.origin != 'http://www.domain.com'){ return }
    console.log('revieced message: ', e.data);
    player.Resume({ uuid: e.data.rid, title: e.data.rtitle });                      

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.text = "player.ready(function () { player.ima(adOptions);player.ima.requestAds(); window.SubtitlesOctopusOnLoad = function () { var options = { video: player.tech_.el_, subUrl: e.data.subtitleUrl || '<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>/files/<?php echo validation::safeOutputToScreen($file->subtitle); ?>', availableFonts: fonts, workerUrl: '<?php echo PLUGIN_WEB_ROOT; ?>/mediaplayer/assets/players/videojs/worker.js'};window.octopusInstance = new SubtitlesOctopus(options); window.octopusInstance.resize();}; if (SubtitlesOctopus) { SubtitlesOctopusOnLoad(); } });";

    $('#subtitles').replaceWith(script);                        

}, false);
```

The script.text contains the data I want to retain in "e.data.subtitleUrl"

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I have made an example. You can check it.

```js
$('#click-div').click(function(e){
 var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.text = 'alert($("#added-script").data("subtitleUrl"));'
  script.dataset.subtitleUrl = 'Hold the data';
  script.setAttribute('id', 'added-script');
  $('#element-to-replace').replaceWith(script); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='click-div'>
  Click
</div>
<div id='element-to-replace'></div>
```

I've added id to `script` element created in function.

You could try `data()` method to keep your data.

```
eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    console.log('origin: ', e.origin);

    // Check if origin is proper
    if( e.origin != 'http://domain.com' || e.origin != 'http://www.domain.com'){ return }
    console.log('revieced message: ', e.data);
    player.Resume({ uuid: e.data.rid, title: e.data.rtitle });                      

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.text = "player.ready(function () { player.ima(adOptions);player.ima.requestAds(); window.SubtitlesOctopusOnLoad = function () { var options = { video: player.tech_.el_, subUrl: $('#added-script').data('subtitle-url') || '<?php echo WEB_ROOT; ?>/files/<?php echo validation::safeOutputToScreen($file->subtitle); ?>', availableFonts: fonts, workerUrl: '<?php echo PLUGIN_WEB_ROOT; ?>/mediaplayer/assets/players/videojs/worker.js'};window.octopusInstance = new SubtitlesOctopus(options); window.octopusInstance.resize();}; if (SubtitlesOctopus) { SubtitlesOctopusOnLoad(); } });";
    script.dataset.subtitleUrl = e.data.subtitleUrl;
    script.setAttribute('id', 'added-script');
    $('#subtitles').replaceWith(script);                        

}, false);
```

Then you could get the subtitleUrl by `$('#added-script').data('subtitle-url')`.

Comment: Do you mean `script.dataset.subtitleUrl` is `undefined`?

Comment: yea its showing up as undefined - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: It's another problem. Where does `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` occur? Please show me the error code. `script.dataset.subtitleUrl` doesn't read property 'data'.

Comment: Don't use `e.data.subtitileUrl`, use `$('#added-script').data('subtitle-url')`. You can't access CURRENT `e` in the function written in `script.text`.

Comment: The main problem is that when using replaceWith() it loads the script outside of the eventer so i think thats why its causing that data read error, and I don't know how to fix that. the "script.text" had e.data.subtitleUrl. the data attribute is still trying to get the event data.

Comment: What i need is to be able to use the event data outside eventer, which doesn't seem to let me.

Comment: `script.dataset.subtitleUrl = e.data.subtitleUrl` makes the `<script></script>` element holds the subtitileUrl data. So you can access `e.data.subtitileUrl` by `$('#added-script').data('subtitle-url')` out of the eventer.

Comment: thats nice but im getting <script data-subtitle-url="undefined"> with the "message event"